# Accidentally deployed two identical contracts on blockchain. How can I pick the one I wish to interact with?

Tags: truffle, contract-invocation, truffle-contract, truffle-deployment

I deployed two identical contracts on the same blockchain.

**contract V1**   address:`0x48A2a37fF1Cff6eB1984aCA7fCA4cAa25B1C9287`

**contract V2**   address:`0xdfaDE9c110eBD5C00243Ca0b3AdCf5B73A8f0e42`

However I would like to interact with the **contract V1** where I already had some data mapped, yet, when using commands in the truffle console terminal it defaults to contacting the **contract V2**

```
let smartContract = await contract.deployed()
```

`contract.address` always returns `0xdfaDE9c110eBD5C00243Ca0b3AdCf5B73A8f0e42` an address of **contract V2**

Does anyone here know truffle commands to interact with the contract directly by its address instead of by its deployed name? So I might connect to **contract V1** .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this command line :

```
let smartContract = await contract.at("0x48A2a37fF1Cff6eB1984aCA7fCA4cAa25B1C9287")
```

`smartContract` will then refer to **contract V1**.

Comment: Thanks, man. I will test this out. If it works I will name this as solved.